# Set specific Fraction or PlayTime for Child Animations in AnimatorSet

Tags: android-animation, objectanimator, animator, animatorset

I have two different `AnimatorSet`, `AnimatorSetX` and `AnimatorSetY`. These animation sets have child animations that have **different** animation durations.

My purpose is, based on `AnimatorSetX`'s current time, set different time for `AnimatorSetY`'s child animations.

Below approach is working but it sets same `playTime` for all child animations. I want to give different play times for each child animation.

```
long currentPlayTime = animatorSetX.getCurrentPlayTime();
animatorSetY.setCurrentPlayTime(currentPlayTime);
animatorSetY.start();
```

So in order to solve this, Iterated all child animations and set different play times, but somehow it did not work

```
    List<Animator> animators = animatorSetY.getChildAnimations();
    for (Animator anim : animators) {
        if (anim instanceof ObjectAnimator) {
            ((ObjectAnimator) anim).setCurrentPlayTime(currentAnimationPlayTime);
        } else if (anim instanceof ValueAnimator) {
            ((ValueAnimator) anim).setCurrentPlayTime(currentAnimationPlayTime);
        }
    }
```

I could not figure out why it is not working? Any one can help or give me a clue?